# Base class undefined?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have no idea why I'm getting this error except that it has to do with the includes.

Base class header file:

```
#pragma once

#include "Player.h"
#include "TestObject.h"
#include <glm\glm.hpp>
#include <GL\glew.h>

class GameObject
{
//unrelated code
};
```

Derived class header file:

```
#pragma once

#include "GameObject.h"
#include <glm\glm.hpp>
#include <glm\gtc\matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm\gtc\type_ptr.hpp>

class Player : public GameObject
{
//unrelated code
};
```

error message:

```
Error   C2504   'GameObject': base class undefined
```

And here are the includes for both cpp files:

base:

```
#include "GameObject.h"
#include "Player.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <glm\glm.hpp>
```

derived:

```
#include "Player.h"
#include "GameObject.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <glm\glm.hpp>
```

Comment: You're having a circular dependency between your headers. I don't remember what it does but you might want to forward declare your dependencies if you only use pointers to them in the header files. (GameObject should not have an #include to Player.)

Comment: `GameObject.h` includes `Player.h`. The first real line of code in the resulting stew is `class Player : public GameObject`, which has not, at that point, been defined. Get rid of your `#include "player.h"` in GameObject.h.

Comment: Okay it works now, thanks guys. Stupid mistake i know :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the compiler goes to compile your `base.cpp` file, it runs the preprocessor to perform *textual substitution* of all `#include` directives with their contents. This substitution is "dumb," it is effectively a copy-and-paste operation that you can control slightly with other preprocessor directives like `#pragma` or `#ifdef`, et cetera.

The first part of this process is to replace `#include "GameObject.h"`, which has a `#pragma once`. The compiler hasn't copied this file into the resulting TU yet, so it does so, records that it has (for later `#pragma once` checks) and recursively continues on.

This means the next thing it does is copy in `Player.h`, which also has a `#pragma` but also hasn't yet been seen, and thus the copy continues. Then it continues on recursively.

This means the *next* thing it does is try to replace the `#include "GameObject.h"` copied in by `Player.h`. But it has already seen `GameObject.h` so it skips this line and continues on.

The net result is that after pre-processing your source file is arranged roughly like:

```
class Player : public GameObject
{
//unrelated code
};

class GameObject
{
//unrelated code
};
```

This is the actual code the compiler ends up seeing, and naturally can't be compiled because by the time you are defining `Player` you have not yet defined the base class `GameObject`.